# Java ServerSocket throwing an IOException when binding to a remote IP address

Tags: java, serversocket

So I am trying to bind and listen to a port on my schools server for an assignment in my networking class.  What I am running into is when I create the ServerSocket in java I constantly get an IOException, even when I attempt to bind to a port that is on the upper bands.

I initially attempt to bind to port 1088 (more or less out of high hopes) but then if that is unsuccessful I will try to bind to a random port above 1024 (anything lower is reserved on the server).

Here's what I got:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Random;


public class main 
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        boolean connected = true;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        int welcomePortNum = new Integer(args[0]);
        if(welcomePortNum >= 65536)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid welcome port number, terminating execution.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        do
        {
            connected = true;
            System.out.println(welcomePortNum);
            try
            {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(welcomePortNum, 5, InetAddress.getByName("loki.ist.unomaha.edu"));
            }   catch(UnknownHostException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Could not connect to 'loki.ist.unomaha.edu'.");
                connected = false;
                //System.exit(1);
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Could not get the I/O for the connection to loki.ist.unomaha.edu.");
                connected = false;
                //System.exit(1);
            }
            if(connected == false)
                welcomePortNum = r.nextInt(64512) + 1024;
            System.out.println(connected);
        }
        while(connected == false);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of using `ServerSocket`, you should use `Socket` (with host and port of the remote server) to connect to the remote server, and read data from it.

Answer (score 2):

Java `ServerSockets` don't 'connect to remote hosts'. They can be *bound* to *local* IP addresses, and that is what the constructor you are using is for.

**EDIT**
Comments on the assignment.

1. The 'associate IP address' part of step 2 is both incorrect and unnecessary, and makes it impossible for you to test at home. Unless your server is actually running on that host, the instruction he has given you cannot possibly work, and in any case it is not generally done in servers. Just pass null for the IP address parameter, which lets the socket accept connections from any local IP address, and add a comment linking to this answer. And the correct word is not 'associate' but 'bind'. If the assignment had used the correct terminology, your confusion between 'connect' and 'bind' wouldn't have arisen.
2. I don't understand step 3 either. There are no clients to initialize the state *of* until one of them connects, and *then* is the time to initialize its state. I don't know what he means by 'mark that connection as inactive' either. All you have to do is close the accepted Socket for that client.
3. Step 4, 'wait for an event', is unimplementable as a discrete step if you are using threads as suggested. The function is distributed over the connection-accepting thread and all the connection-handling threads.
4. I don't consider that you should be given the option of using select() at this stage. I would have made that a subsequent assignment, partly for pedagogical reasons and partly to ensure you learn both.

Comment: See our professor told us that we needed to use a server socket to read in data from a remote host. http://cs.unomaha.edu/~stanw/131/csci3550/prog2.pdf  That' the link to the assignment